# Curl - set write method as param from class in writeData

Tags: c++, curl

I try to push method from class "curl_connector" to curl function.

Let see code:

```
size_t curl_connector::write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) {
    size_t written;
    written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
    return written;
}

//execute from curl_connector.cpp and this class method
res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, std::bind(&curl_connector::write_data,this));
```

I got error, and application get closed.

I try that:

```
std::bind(&curl_connector::write_data);
std::bind(&curl_connector::write_data,curl_connector::getInstance()); //curl_connector is a singleton pattern
```

If you give me an example how to to that, tell me how to do the same when write_data is in other class.

Comment: Libcurl is a C library. It wants a C linkage function. You cannot feed it C++ objects like the unnameable results of bind.

Comment: @n.m. can u give me an example of that?
For the same instance (this) and for other class

Comment: Look at the [official example](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html).